# Parse CSV in 2D Python Object

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i am trying to do Analysis on a CSV file which looks like this:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1594512094.39 | 51 |
| 1594512094.74 | 76 |
| 1594512098.07 | 50.9 |
| 1594512099.59 | 76.80000305 |
| 1594512101.76 | 50.9 |

i am using pandas to import each column:

```
dataFrame = pandas.read_csv('iot_telemetry_data.csv')
graphDataHumidity: object = dataFrame.loc[:, "humidity"]
graphTime: object = dataFrame.loc[:, "ts"]
```

My Problem is i need to make a tuple of both columns, to filter the values of a specific time range, so for example i have my timestampBeginn of "1594512109.13668" and my "timestampEnd of "1594512129.37415" and i want to have the corresponding values to generate for example the mean value of the value of the specific time range.

I didn't find any solutions to this online and i don't know any libraries which solve this problem.

Comment: You read it in DataFrame, then just work with it, don't create separate variables for columns. You may want to use `timestamp` as index though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first filter the rows which timestamp values are between the 'start' and 'end.' Then you can calculate the values of the filtered rows, as follows:
(But, in the sample data, it seems that there is no row, which timestamp are between the range from 1594512109.13668 to 1594512129.37415. You can edit the range values as what you want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('iot_telemetry_data.csv')

start = 159451219.13668
end = 1594512129.37415

df = df[(df['timestamp'] >= start) & (df['timestamp'] <= end)]

average = df['value'].mean()
print(average)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I get the result "NaN" Not a number i guess? Could this because of a error in the CSV ? The CSV is acutally bigger with 405k rows

Edit: actually this returns a empty dataframe

Comment: @cpp_student as I mentioned, no timestamp values in the dataset are between 1594512109.13668 and 1594512129.37415. Check your range value. NaN will be printed when no row is remained.